# The Steam App Won't Connect to Wifi

Tags: steam, middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I have a new computer. When I first got it, I downloaded steam and 3 games. After that, i did not use it for 3 months. I recently started using it again. During the time that i did not use it, I bought a couple games on other computers. Now whenever i open the steam app, it says that I am not connected to the wifi even though I am connected. When I go to the steam store, steam works and says those games are added to my library, but when I go to my steam library, the games aren't there. After that, i tried downloading the games through the store, but it won't download.

BTW, I am trying to download shadow of mordor

Comment: This sounds like something is blocking the steam client from downloading your games list.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs how do we make it work then

Comment: I don't know. I think the best location to ask that is through Steam support. https://support.steampowered.com/ Arqade is really not the right place for this, because we're focused on a Q&A format, while this is more a question that requires a lot of back and forth to really work out, or a lot of trial and error

Comment: Where's the WiFi point? Is it at home?

Answer (score 0):

Something is blocking your application from accessing the internet.
You need to disable windows firewall by going to your Control Center then going to security, you can also temporarily disable any anti-malware or antivirus programs you may have installed on your computer to test this out. Once you have done that, and it still doesn't work, you need to contact steam support as there's nothing further we could really do on SE